# Deep linking with Flex4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, struts, deep-linking

I am adding deep linking to a mixed `Flex4/Struts` application.

1) Is there anything new in `Flex4` regarding deep linking?
If I remember correctly, standard `Flex3` deep linking was cumbersome and did not always work in all browsers on all platforms. Is it still the case?
So is `SWFAddress` still the one most people use for DL?

2) Can I avoid using `"#"` when working with `SWFAddress`?
That would be very useful for me to use "?" since I might need to blend it with `Struts`.

3) In case I need to pass parameters via a link from Flex to `Struts` or vice versa,
is it even possible? 
Say, I need to forward to specific tab and populate some values on that page (and optionally submit).  Can it at least work in `Flex-to-Flex` case?

Any code samples?

Please advise.